# remove tricky tags using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Trying to remove the following using reg so the outcome is only fa-*

```
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-align-right:before { content: fa-content($fa-var-align-right); }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-amazon:before { content: fa-content($fa-var-amazon); }
```

The outcome should look like the following:
**align-right, amazon**

Can someone give me some type of clue how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the work in sublime text :

```
(?<=\}-)(.*?)(?=(:))
```

Background about regex lookaround may help to better understand the previous expression : 
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: How would I copy that portion only and remove everything else?